# How can I select one row for each week in a date range that spans more than a year?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

In my postgreSQL data base, I have a table with columns of dates and prices. ('transdate' and 'price')

I would like to form a query which selects one row for each week over a date range which spans more than one year.

From another question/answer here, I implemented this code which works for date ranges of less than a year:

```
;with cte as  
(  
  select *,  
  row_number() over (partition by Extract (week from transdate) order by transdate desc) as rn   
  from "tablename" where transdate between '06-01-1999' and '06-01-1999'::timestamp + `'50 week'::interval  
)  
select transdate, price from cte where rn = 1 order by transdate;
```

However, when I extend the interval greater than 50 weeks, it still only selects a max of 12 months.

How can I re-write this code to select one date/price from every week in the range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that week numbers wrap around at year boundaries but you want to look at the week number *and* the year at the same time. Lucky for you, you can PARTITION BY several things at once:

```
row_number() over (
    partition by extract(week from transdate),
                 extract(year from transdate)
    order by transdate desc
) as rn
```

Comment: Yay! That works. I had tried extract(week from transdata) + extract(year from transdate) thinking it worked on a number, but no go.

Comment: @JohnSmith: The problem with `week+year` is that `1+2012` and `2+2011` are the same thing, the addition mingles things that need to be kept separate.